# How can I use the taxonomy identifier instead of the id, using the REST API?

Tags: sitecore-api, content-hub, taxonomy

I am working on a connector with a Sitecore Content Hub environnement. I am using the REST API, sending POST request to create some Assets.

I wonder if there is a way to set a taxonomy relation with its identifier instead of the id ?

For example to set `FinalLifeCycleStatusToAsset` with `M.Final.LifeCycle.Status.Approved` instead of `544`.

My request is a `POST` to `https://{{hostname}}/api/entities/`

With the following body :

```
{
    "properties":{
        "Title":"REST API Asset",
        "Description": {
            "en-US": "<p>Description</p>"
        }
    },
    "relations": {
        "FinalLifeCycleStatusToAsset": {
            "parent": {
                "href": "http://{{hostname}}/api/entities/544"
            }
        }
    },
    "entitydefinition":{
        "href":"http://{{hostname}}/api/entitydefinitions/M.Asset"
    }

}
```

I have tried to set href to `http://{{hostname}}/api/entities/identifier/M.Final.LifeCycle.Status.Approved` by it gives me in response this message : "Unable to match the route 'EntityById' template with the available route values."

To conclude, is it possible to use `M.Final.LifeCycle.Status.Approved` instead of `544` when created an asset ? And how can I do that ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation and asking the question to Sitecore team. It seems not possible to use the identifier instead of the id in the REST API relations when creating an entity.